# Context in ArrayAdapter()

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working for the first time in android studio with java.
I am trying to make an app where the `SeekBar` is used to make a time table.

Previously I've made a `ListView` of family members and an audioplayer `SeekBar`.

But the role of the "Context" which is `MainActivity.this`  or `this` is not clear to me.

**Code**

```
 seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.timeTableList);

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean fromUser) {
            int  seekbarNumber = i;

            ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
                arrayList.add(seekbarNumber*j);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java `this` inside any non-static method refers to the instance of the object whose method has been called. In your code when calling `seekbar#setOnSeekBarChangeListner` you are required to pass an instance of a class which implements the `SeekBar#OnSeekBarChangeListner` interface, you do that by declaring and instantiating a class at the same time this is called an Anonymous class in Java (you can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)), Anonymous class shadows the variables of enclosing scope that means inside the Anonymous class `this` refers to the instance of the Anonymous class, However the `ArrayAdapter` constructor requires an instance of a `Context` class or any subclass like `Activity` as first parameter. To access the variables of enclosing scope you have to refer them by the class name in which they are declared like In your case `MainActivity.this` refers to the instances of the `MainActivity` class which is a subclass of `Activity` class which is a subclass of `Context` when you pass `MainActivity.this` to `ArrayAdapter` constructor you pass the instance of your `MainActivity` class.